# Workflow works only on items created by me

Tags: workflow

I  have administrative permissions on sharepoint. I have a sharepoint list showing employees requesting for Christmas benefits. There are two views: All items and Control. Control is available only for a specific group and has three additional columns filled in by reviewers.

[image]

All requests will be reviewed to check if they were submitted correctly. I've created the workflow to send email to the person who created request when a field in column "Meets formal requirements" is changed by reviewer to "No" .

[image]

I've tested the workflow on the items created by me, and when I changed the value of the field to "No", I received an email. However, when I change the value of the field to "No" for the items which weren't created by me (a sharepoint member), workflow is triggered but gets stuck with error "item doesn't exist".
[image]

The item does exist and I have access to it. Why workflow doesn't see it?

Comment: Can you try to run the workflow manually on items that were not created by you. Just to check if you are getting same error. I assume this is some permission related issue so want to double check.

Comment: Could you check this https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/